# .htaccess rewrite rule from directory/ to root

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, root

I'd like a  rewrite rule that takes directory/file to /file
As everything can be found on the root for this case and I don't want to rewrite the source code of the file to point to the root ../ instead I'd prefer htaccess for this situation in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this in the htaccess file in your document root

```
Redirect 301 /directory/file /file
```